# Mongodb how to update many and set profile specific to id

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a list of ids called `batch` i want to update all of them to set a field called `fetched` to true.

**Original Test Collection**

```
[{
    "user_id": 1,
  },
  {
    "user_id": 2,
  }
]
```

**batch variable**

```
[1, 2]
```

**UpdateMany**:

```
mongodb["test"].update_many({"user_id": {"$in": batch}}, {"$set": {"fetched": True}})
```

I can do that using the above statement.

I also have another variable called `user_profiles` which is a list/array of json objects. I now ALSO want to set a field `profile` to be the profile found in the list(user_profiles) where the id matches the user_id/batch(id) i am updating.

**user_profiles**

```
[{

    "id": 1,
    "name": "john"

  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "jane"

  }
]
```

**Expected Final Result**

```
[{
    "user_id": 1,
    "fetched": true,
    "profile": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "john"
    }
  },
  {
    "user_id": 2,
    "fetched": true,
    "profile": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "jane"
    }
  }
]
```

I have a millions of these documents so i am trying to keep performance in mind.

Comment: That's not possible with a single `$set`. You'll need multiple queries since you're setting different values in different documents.

Comment: @rdas :( Do you know the best way to do this thats optimised for performance. I am working with millions of documents.

Comment: Use the first query as-is. For the second profile part you can try using a bulk query.

Answer (score -1):

You'll want to use `db.collection.bulkWrite`, see the `updateOne` [example in the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#updateone-and-updatemany)

If you've got millions you'll want to batch the `bulkWrite`s into smaller chunks that work with your database server's capabilities.

Edit:
@Kay I just re-read the second part of your question which I didn't address earlier.  You may want to try the [`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) stage of the aggregation pipeline.  Be careful though since it will overwrite the existing collection so if you don't project all fields you could lose data. Definitely worth using a temporary collection for testing first.

Finally, you could also just create a [view](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/views/) based on the aggregation query (with `$lookup`) if you don't absolutely need that data physically stored in the same collection.

Comment: updateOne updates a single document in the collection that matches the filter. If multiple documents match, updateOne will update the first matching document only. I don't think thats what i need here. Im trying to match up the ids here to update the profile the id belongs to

Comment: @Kay I didn't say anything about `updateOne`, you can still use `updateMany` within a `bulkWrite` so set the `fetched` field. Did you follow the link I provided? The second example I provided is for `updateMany`.